# Can anyone help me out to try pagination for the below code...!

Tags: php, html, pagination

Well below i have attached the table structure kindly go through it.

I would like to get serial no as my 1st column followed by id and name. serial no should continue for pagination rather then starting from 1st.
Thanks in advance..

Table structure is

```
create table departments (

 id INT(20) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 

name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL);
```

---

```
<html>
<head>
<?php
    $db_connection = new mysqli("localhost","root","","emp_app");
    if($db_connection->connect_error)
        die("connection failed".$db_connection->connect_error); 
?>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Serial no </th>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>name</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $sql_query = "select * from departments";
        $result = $db_connection->query($sql_query);
        if($result->num_rows > 0){
            while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                 echo "<tr>";
                 echo "<td>".$rows["id"]."<td>";
                 echo "<td>".$rows["name"]."<td>";
                 echo "<tr>";
            }
        }
        ?>
    </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a good example how to add pagination in php [pagination in php](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_paging_php.htm)
**Refrence link is using depricated mysql query you need to replace with mysqli query**

```
 $num_rec_per_page=10;

    if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 
    $start_from = ($page-1) * $num_rec_per_page; 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM departments LIMIT $start_from, $num_rec_per_page"; 
    $rs_result = $db_connection->query ($sql); //run the query
$serial=1;
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc) { 
          //code here 
echo $serial;
$serial++;
    }; 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM departments";  //select query for total records
    $rs_result = $db_connection->query($sql); //run the query
    $total_records =$rs_result->num_rows;  //count number of records
    $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $num_rec_per_page); 

    echo "<a href='pagination.php?page=1'>".'|<'."</a> "; // Goto 1st page  

    for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
                echo "<a href='pagination.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> "; 
    }; 
    echo "<a href='pagination.php?page=$total_pages'>".'>|'."</a> "; // Goto last page
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton.The above code cleared my doubt to some extent. Thank you.

Comment: But i want to make u clear that serial no and id is totally different. Id will be fetched from database where as serial no goes like 1 2 3 4 5 etc and i want it to flow through irrespective to pagination. How can i do that? Can u  direct me please.!!

Comment: check the code i have added echo $serial;
$serial++; into loop . this will print 1-10 on every page

Comment: But i want to continue it . Like if it ends in page 1 as 1-10 then in 2nd page it need to start from 11 and so on.

Comment: replace $serial=1; with $serial=1;  with $serial= $start_from

Comment: $ris: Your a genius.. Thanks

Comment: i don't have reputation do that.Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You could append the URL to add a get variable that will serve as your pagination number i.e. youurl.com/?pagination=1 or 2 or 3

Then in your code add

```
$pagenumber = $_GET["pagination"];
$offset = $pagenumber * 5; //The number 5 is how many results per page if you wanted 10 results per page this would be 10
```

Where you have

```
 $sql_query = "select * from departments";
```

You can change to

```
 $sql_query = "select * from departments" LIMIT 5 OFFSET '$offset';
```

Which is basically saying; only give me 5 results starting from the pagination row (which is 5 results x page 2 or 3

Comment: You need to the SQL statement $sql_query = "select * from departments";

and also add a page number variable somewhere; I suggested adding a GET variable to the URL for the page number. Are you familiar with those? You can see at W3 Schools how to do that.

Comment: yup am clear with the page number, all i need now is how to add serial no like 1 2 3 4 5 continuously from 1st page to last page. Trust me am not speaking about id to make you clear....

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<?php
    $db_connection = new mysqli("localhost","root","","emp_app");
    if($db_connection->connect_error)
        die("connection failed".$db_connection->connect_error); 

    $num_rec_per_page=5;
    if (isset($_GET["page"])) { 
        $page  = $_GET["page"]; 
    } else { 
        $page=1; 
    }; 
    $start_from = ($page-1) * $num_rec_per_page;    
?>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Serial no </th>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>name</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $sql_query =  "SELECT * FROM departments LIMIT $start_from, $num_rec_per_page";
        $result = $db_connection->query($sql_query);
        if($result->num_rows > 0){
            while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                 echo "<tr>";
                 echo "<td>".$rows["id"]."<td>";
                 echo "<td>".$rows["name"]."<td>";
                 echo "<tr>";
            }
        }
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM departments";  //select query for total records
        $rs_result = $db_connection->query($sql); //run the query
        $total_records =$rs_result->num_rows;  //count number of records
        $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $num_rec_per_page); 

        echo "<a href='index.php?page=1'>".'|<'."</a> "; // Goto 1st page  

        for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
            echo "<a href='index.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> "; 
        }; 
        echo "<a href='index.php?page=$total_pages'>".'>|'."</a> ";
        ?>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: @ris : This where the changes i made as you suggested.